# Django, static image with hash in the file name

Tags: django, static

When you use `{% static path/to/image.png %}` tag in a template, it gets replaced by `path/to/image.some-hash.png`

My less file points to image files as `url(path/to/image.png)`
I compile it using GruntFile watch.

I wonder if there is a way to rewrite the path in the resulting css to be `path/to/image.some-hash.png` so that I can take advantage of the hashed file name.

I'm using the hash to cache-bust. in essence, I'm caching static files on the client side

Comment: What are the advantages? What is the reason to add a hash to name of static file?

Comment: I'm using it to cache-bust. in essence, I'm caching static files on the client side.

Comment: I guess you need to add this detail to you description.

Comment: I believe this is a related question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42969399/how-to-use-images-loaded-with-webpack-in-django-templates the only difference is that I use Webpack to add a hash to the file names for cache busting.